# Looping Through Instr VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have to filter all the blank rows in column `X` and based on values specified in columns `M`, `W`, `V`, I have to populate column `X`.

I have attached a part of the code wherein I am trying to loop through all visible rows, however VBA is looping through all the rows and that's changing all the non-blank values as well. Please could you guide me on fixing this? Thanks in advance!

```
Set rng5 = Sheet1.Range("A2" & ":N" & last_row2)
With Sheet1.Range("A1") .AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="=" .Select

    For m = 1 To rng5.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
        If InStr(rng5.Cells(RowIndex:=m, ColumnIndex:="M").Value, "ABC") > 0 _
        And InStr(rng5.Cells(RowIndex:=m, ColumnIndex:="M").Value, "EFG") = 0 And _
        And InStr(rng5.Cells(RowIndex:=m, ColumnIndex:="W").Value, "123") = 0 _
        And InStr(rng5.Cells(RowIndex:=m, ColumnIndex:="V").Value, "Non") = 0 Then

            rng5.Cells(RowIndex:=m, ColumnIndex:="X").Value = "XYZ"

        ElseIf InStr(rng5.Cells(RowIndex:=m, ColumnIndex:="M").Value, "MNO") > 0 _
        And InStr(rng5.Cells(RowIndex:=m, ColumnIndex:="M").Value, "567") = 0 _
        And InStr(rng5.Cells(RowIndex:=m, ColumnIndex:="W").Value, "123") = 0 _
        And InStr(rng5.Cells(RowIndex:=m, ColumnIndex:="V").Value, "Non ") = 0 Then

            rng5.Cells(RowIndex:=m, ColumnIndex:="X").Value = "UVW"

        End If
    Next m
```

Comment: No luck @QHarr :( Moreover, the cells neither contain constants nor formulae. They contain strings and I have to check presence of specific strings to design the condition

Comment: You have an extra `And` in your `And ... "EFG") = 0 And` statement

Comment: Thanks for the callout @Marcucciboy2 but that's just a type, happened during pasting the code. I guess. This code just doesn't seem to work. It gives different result on every iteration :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have (e.g.) 10 visible rows then this will loop from 1 to 10

```
 For m = 1 To rng5.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
```

So when you're at (e.g.) m = 5 this:

```
 rng5.Cells(RowIndex:=m, ColumnIndex:="X")
```

will point to the 5th row in `rng5`.  That's not necessarily the same thing as the 5th *visible* row in `rng5`

Your `With` block doesn't seem to be connected to the contained code, so you could remove it.

Try something like this:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim rw As Range, rng5 As Range, mVal

    Set rng5 = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set rng5 = rng5.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng5.Rows.Count - 1) 'exclude headers

    Sheet1.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="="

    For Each rw In rng5.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows

        If InStr(rw.Cells(1, "W").Value, "123") = 0 And _
           InStr(rw.Cells(1, "V").Value, "Non") = 0 Then

            mVal = rw.Cells(1, "M").Value

            If InStr(mVal, "ABC") > 0 And InStr(mVal, "EFG") = 0 Then

                rw.Cells(1, "X").Value = "XYZ"

            ElseIf InStr(mVal, "MNO") > 0 And InStr(mVal, "567") = 0 Then

                rw.Cells(1, "X").Value = "UVW"

            End If

        End If

    Next rw

End Sub
```

Comment: That's exactly what's happening @Tim Williams. What shall I do to fix it? I am a beginner in VBA and I want to loop through the 5th visible row in rng5, not the normal 5th row, like you mentioned above.

Comment: The code is terrific @Tim Williams and does exactly what I want and looks 10X cleaner than what I had written. Thanks a ton for your help, you are a saviour! :)